# How to put multiple values as one key using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to group a certain group of numbers to one value. For example, the numbers 59,58,57 should give a value of 1. However, I cannot figure out why this is not working.

```
b = 59
a = {'59,58,27':1}
print(a.get(b))
>>>None
```

Comment: `'59,58,27'` is a string literal. There's no way for this to work and get the benefits of a dict. You need each number as a separate key, all with `1` stored as the value against that key.

Answer (score 4):

Your key is a string, while you're trying to use a number as a index. Your key and your index are two different types. That won't work.

If you want multiple keys to point to the same value, you can simply assign that value to each key *individually*:

```
keys = '59,58,27'
value = 1
d = {k: value for k in map(int, keys.split(','))}
# d: {59: 1, 58: 1, 27: 1}
```

Comment: Grammar Nazis never sleep :P